# Toggle one button at at time Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've been playing with this for the last hour and can't seem to figure out how to have one button toggle at a time. Also trying to have the button change to different color  So if I click button1 it toggles. If I then click button2, then button1 untoggles and button2 toggles. 
Here's what I have so far

```
<div class="Demo-boot" style="padding:30px;">
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="button">Button1</button>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="button">Button2</button>
  </div>
```

Here it is in action: 
http://www.bootply.com/MaxkTJs3HH

Comment: It sounds like you want radio buttons. http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons-checkbox-radio

Comment: I prefer regular buttons and not radio buttons

Comment: I've added a solution that doesn't use radio buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first add some ids to the buttons

```
<div class="Demo-boot" style="padding:30px;">
  <button id="button_one" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="button">Button1</button>
  <button id="button_two" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="button">Button2</button>
</div>
```

Next add some jquery

```
$('#button_one').click(function (e) {
    $('#button_two').removeClass('active')
});

$('#button_two').click(function (e) {
    $('#button_one').removeClass('active')
});
```

the running product : http://www.bootply.com/tT4yYWxjyk

Comment: The buttons should start with `aria-pressed="false"` to indicate that they are toggle buttons. http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons-single-toggle

Answer (score 1):

You need to set it up in a button group like this::

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary active">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked> Button 1
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> Button 2
  </label>
</div>
```